# materialize css button for delete not working

Tags: css, materialize

I have the following code in my node/express file:

```
             {{#each allimages}}
        <div class="col m3 14">
            <div class="card hoverable">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <a href="/uploads/{{imageName}}" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="This is a test">
                        <img src="/uploads/{{imageName}}">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="card-action2 right-align">
                    <form action="/user/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light red">
                            <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                    <form action="/user/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light blue">
                            <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
```

I can see my delete button in red but when I click on it it does not delete the file. When I am using  and type is set to submit it works perfectly with my route and deletes the file. How can I use the materialize css delete style to submit my delete request form?

Thanks guys for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make it a `button`, not an anchor. You can just add the relevant class definitions to use the styles of a Materialize button:

```
<div class="card-action2 right-align">
  <form action="/user/{{id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-floating btn waves-effect waves-light red">
      <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
    </button>
  </form>

  <a href="2.html">
    <i class="material-icons blue-grey-text">edit</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks BenM, that worked! I am very new to front end so thanks a lot.

Comment: could you also help me with arranging the layout, I have edited my original question with the full block of html code. The image card size needs to be the same for all images of different sizes and the edit amd delete button need to to be side by side. Right now they are arranged in a way that one is above and the other one is in another row below it.

Comment: @AminBaig Please don't move the goalposts. Your edited question should be a follow-up, not just an edit.

Comment: Apologies for that. I guess desperation makes us do stupid things.